# Nodejs Async Waterfall, another flow control?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I'm using async.waterfall, and I want to do some like this:

keeping the result of async.waterfall by returning something likes Promise. So that, I can split those two parts.

```
function Action1(){

    return async.waterfall([
        function step1(callback){
            ...
            callback(null, data);
        },
        function step2(data, callback){
            ...
            callback(null, data);
        },
        function step3(data, callback){
            ...
            callback(null, data);
        }
    ]);
}


Action1().then(function(result){
    // obtain the final result here
});
```

However, what I can find is: the final callback can only be injected into the waterfall function as an argument.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        ...
        callback(null, data);
    },
    function(data, callback) {
        ...
        callback(null, data);
    },
    function(data, callback) {
        ...
        callback(null, data);
    }
], function (err, result) {

    // final callback
    ...
});
```

Is there any suggestion for me, to achieve the expected programming structure? Or any choices other than async allow this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably go for Bluebird.

The `async` code like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Can be written like this (using Blubird):

```
Promise.resolve(['one', 'two']).spread(function(arg1, arg2) {
    // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
    return 'three';
}).then(function(arg1) {
    // arg1 now equals 'three'
    return 'done';
}).then(function(result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

You can refer to http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/coming-from-other-libraries.html#coming-from-async-module for more info.

Comment: I need to call asynchronous functions in each steps. But `Promise.then` need `return` to proceed.